# Fetching json data from local in react

Tags: reactjs, fetch

I could just simply import "./city.json" in my react component. But I want to know why fetch is causing SyntaxError like "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".

my react code,

```
  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("./city.json")
      .then( response => response.json())
      .then( data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err=> console.log(err))
  }
```

./city.json file,

```
{
   "city":[
      {
         "id":"5368361",
         "name":"Los Angeles",
         "country":"US",
         "admin1":"California",
         "lat":"34.0522300",
         "lon":"-118.2436800",
         "pop":"3971883"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/ could help?

Comment: Check browser dev tools to see what the server's response contains (or just enter the full URL in the browser's address and go to it, since it's just a GET request). If it's not JSON (but instead is some default error message in HTML), then check your server configuration and request handlers to understand why the request might be failing. For example, you might need to expose any files/assets/directories to make those files publicly accessible.

Comment: You would also need to tell the client you're trying to access and accept json resource from the server. 
```
fetch('./city.json'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch is most commonly used for fetching resources across the network. The API depends on receiving a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response) object. You cannot simply just fetch a raw file. The syntax will not be what Fetch is expecting.

In theory, you could have a function that `requires` the `json`, and send it in the body of a `Response`, so `fetch` can parse the response. But really, you should probably just `import` or `require` the JSON if it is a local file.

If the file is available via a web server (for example, if you're running localhost:8080) check if you can retrieve the json by browsing http://localhost:8080/city.json. If this returns a 200 response with the JSON in the body of the response, then the `fetch` you have looks good.